# run html/js video player on RaspberryPi without lags

Tags: javascript, html, video, raspberry-pi

I want to realize the following:
A html/css/js project, showing a homescreen where several slideshows are running. By clicking on one, a video gets startet. It has to be run on a RaspberryPi400 at the end.

Now my problem: I wrote everything on my laptop without testing in on a raspberry pi - and the bad surprise:
On the Raspy the fadeout of the slideshow and especially the video playback is lagging horrible. [link to the github](https://github.com/timtombobjohn/videopresi/)

What I tried:
In VLC the videos are replayed without problems.
I tried Chromium and Firefox as browsers, gave 256mb graphical memory in raspi-config.

Can I optimize my code to avoid the lags? Is it possible to use a different video player(like vlc)?
Change some settings in the Raspberry, like "boosting" graphics or something?

Thanks1

Comment: This is not exactly how you ask questions here. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: i've edited the post. Is it okay now?

Comment: have you optimized your videos for playback on this device - framesize, frame rate, codec (ideally something it can decide in hardware) etc?

Comment: yes I think so, I'm already 25fps, 4500kb/s bitrate, h.264.... But in in vlc play it can even play 4k